# Sending Post Request from Google Sheets to Another Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I designed this function which gets called from spreadsheet A to send a post request to another spreadsheet B . I have allowed this link / webapp to be executed with the credentials of the user who is executing it . But even if I try to access the URL . I get a 401 error . Any help is appreciated .

```
function senddetails() {
 var options = {
 "method" : "post",
 "payload" : JSON.stringify({"testRunMethod":"ThisMethod","testRunName":"ThisName"}),
 "muteHttpExceptions": false
 };
 
 UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
 return "Updated"
};
```

Comment: Error 401 is unauthorized access. It is likely that your users don't have access to spreadsheet B and that's why it's happening. Make it execute as you and make sure you have edit rights to spreadsheet B and it should work. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hello Dmitry, Thanks for your insights . But I have permissions to both the sheets . Still got the same error .

Comment: How is this function getting called by spreadsheet A, and how it is trying to access spreadsheet B? What URL are you using? And what does this `payload` refer to? Also, even if you have permissions to access both sheets, the request should include an access token if you are to access it. Your request is not authenticated, so no question you are getting 401.

Comment: Please consider adding the requested information to your question.

Comment: I removed the complexity of 2 worksheets and integrated it into a single worksheet and allowed CORS Allow Origin and it worked fine .

Comment: @RajeshRajamani it's not enough that you have permission, you have to set it to execute "as myself"

Comment: If your issue got solved, please consider posting an answer explaining how you solved it.